# React-Native-Elements card isn't showing the full Image

Tags: image, react-native, react-native-elements

I'm trying to make a card using react-native-elements, however I'm running into an issue with the image component.

the Image is cut off from the top and the bottom; in other words the entire image isn't being displayed. Another issue is that the image is overlapping the Card. Basically the sharp corners of the images are overlapping the round corners of the Card that is displaying the Image.

here is the code of my Card:

```
<Card
image={{uri: 'https://i2-prod.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article14334083.ece/ALTERNATES/s615/3_Beautiful-girl-with-a-gentle-smile.jpg'}}
containerStyle={{borderRadius:10, marginRight:1, marginLeft:1,}}>
<View
    style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}
  >
  <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row'}}>
    <Avatar 
        size="small"
        rounded
        source={{
    uri:
      'https://i2-prod.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article14334083.ece/ALTERNATES/s615/3_Beautiful-girl-with-a-gentle-smile.jpg',
  }}
  />
    <Text>Name</Text>
    </View>
    <View>
    <Text>Date</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
    <Text>Caption of image</Text>
</Card>
```

the issue is in

```
image={{uri: 'https://i2-prod.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article14334083.ece/ALTERNATES/s615/3_Beautiful-girl-with-a-gentle-smile.jpg'}}
containerStyle={{borderRadius:10, marginRight:1, marginLeft:1,}}
```

that is the image that overlaps the card's borders and isn't being shown 100%.

Comment: Avatar's style `width: "100%", height:"100%"`

Comment: I'm sorry, the way I wrote the question must be confusing hold on. I'll edit it. The issue is in the `image={{uri: 'https://i2-prod.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article14334083.ece/ALTERNATES/s615/3_Beautiful-girl-with-a-gentle-smile.jpg'}}
containerStyle={{borderRadius:10, marginRight:1, marginLeft:1,}}`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this prop to thee `Card`:

```
<Card
  image={{uri: 'https://i2-prod.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article14334083.ece/ALTERNATES/s615/3_Beautiful-girl-with-a-gentle-smile.jpg'}}
  imageStyle={{
    width: '200px,
    height: '200px',
   resizeMode: 'cover'
  }}
...
>
```

Try to specify the exact width and height, see the example above.